# Use Firebase Function with error TypeError

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am very new to Node js, I just want to get the data from extenal xml from a website but I got an error from Firebase Function log TypeError: invalid media type. I think it come from when I try to do this task `parseString(xml, function(err, result) { })`

Anyone can help me, it will be great:

Here is my code on firebase function:

```
exports.getRate = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  getRate = () => {
    var url = "https://www.vietcombank.com.vn/ExchangeRates/ExrateXML.aspx";
    https.get(url, function(res) {
      var xml = "";
        res.on('error', function(error){
            console.log(error, 'get data error');

        })
      res.on("data", function(chunk) {
        xml += chunk;
        console.log(xml, 'xml file');
      });
      res.on("end", function() {
        var date = "";
        let rateAUD = {
            code: 'AUD/VND',
            buy: 0,
            sell: 0
          };
          let rateUSD = {
            code: 'USD/VND',
            buy: 0,
            sell: 0
          };
        parseString(xml, function(err, result) {
            console.log(xml, 'xml file');

          date = result.ExrateList.DateTime[0];
          if (result.ExrateList.Exrate[0].$.CurrencyCode == "AUD") {
            rateAUD.buy = result.ExrateList.Exrate[0].$.Buy;
            rateAUD.sell = result.ExrateList.Exrate[0].$.Sell;
          } else {
            console.log("They change the database list");
          }
          if (result.ExrateList.Exrate[18].$.CurrencyCode == "USD") {
            rateUSD.buy = result.ExrateList.Exrate[18].$.Buy;
            rateUSD.sell = result.ExrateList.Exrate[18].$.Sell;
          } else {
            console.log("They change the database list");
          }
          console.log(rateAUD, rateUSD, 'get data');
          uploadDataToServer(date, { rateAUD, rateUSD });
          if(err) {
              console.log(err);
          }
        });
      });
    });
  };

  function uploadDataToServer(date, { rateAUD, rateUSD }) {
    var db = admin.firestore();

    let data = { rateAUD, rateUSD };
    data.timeStamp = date;
    console.log('upload success');

    db.collection("liveRate").add(data),then((err)=> {
        console.log(err);

    });
  }
  return res.status(200)
  .type('application / json')
  .send('hello')
});
```

'
When I run the same code on another Nodejs playground, it works well.
Here is the link: https://repl.it/repls/MaroonSlateblueProfiler
So weird!
Ps: my payment option is ON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the client is sending the server what may or may not be a valid media type in an encoding the server cannot understand (as per the Content-Encoding header the client packaged with the request message).

Please try to set the `content-type` to `xml`:

```
getRate = () => {
    var options = {
      hostname: "www.vietcombank.com.vn",
      port: 443,
      path: "/ExchangeRates/ExrateXML.aspx",
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/xml'
      }
    };

    https.get(options, function(res) {
      ...
    });
}
```

Comment: I just change it but still have the same error. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: No, it works, the server delay. Thanks, mate. But I got another error, the functions is executed but it takes too long, and it couldn't finish the job